# Enum Bitwise operation returning wrong value

Tags: c#, enums, bitwise-operators

I have color selection `enum` that represents Red, Blue, Green and None.

```
[Flags]
public enum SelectedColor
{
    None, Red, Blue, Green
}
```

When I create a new enum and set it to `Red` and `Green` then check if `Blue` is set, it returns `true`.  `Blue` was never set anywhere.

For example:

```
SelectedColor selectedColor = SelectedColor.Red;
selectedColor |= SelectedColor.Green; //Add Green to Selection

//Check if blue is set
Debug.Log("Blue Selected hasFlag? : " + hasFlag(selectedColor, SelectedColor.Blue));

//Check if blue is set
Debug.Log("Blue Selected isSet? : " + isSet(selectedColor, SelectedColor.Blue));
```

Output:

> Blue Selected hasFlag? : False
>
> Blue Selected isSet? : True

hasFlag and isSet function:

```
bool hasFlag(SelectedColor source, SelectedColor value)
{
    int s1 = (int)source;
    return Convert.ToBoolean((s1 & Convert.ToInt32(((int)value) == s1)));
}


bool isSet(SelectedColor source, SelectedColor critValue)
{
    //return ((source & critValue) == critValue);
    return ((source & critValue) != 0);
}
```

As you can see, my `isSet` function is returning the wrong value. I have tried both `return ((source & critValue) == critValue)` and `return ((source & critValue) != 0);` in it but they both still failed. This should work according to my research on SO and [this](http://www.alanzucconi.com/2015/07/26/enum-flags-and-bitwise-operators/) post.

My `hasFlag` function is fine but why is the `isSet` function returning the wrong value?

*Please note that I am using .NET 3.5, so I can't use .NET 4 enum helper functions such as [`HasFlag`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.hasflag(v=vs.110).aspx)*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you do not specify values for enums, sequential numbers are assigned to to them like so:

```
[Flags]
public enum SelectedColor // WRONG
{
    None  = 0, // 000
    Red   = 1, // 001
    Blue  = 2, // 010
    Green = 3  // 011 <-- Not the next power of two!
}
```

Then this happens:

```
selectedColor = SelectedColor.Red; // 001
selectedColor |= SelectedColor.Green; // (001 | 011 ) == 011, which is still Green
```

You need to use powers of two for `[Flags]` enums, as follows:

```
[Flags]
public enum SelectedColor // CORRECT
{
    None  = 0, // 000
    Red   = 1, // 001
    Blue  = 2, // 010
    Green = 4  // 100
}
```

Then it works correctly:

```
selectedColor = SelectedColor.Red; // 001
selectedColor |= SelectedColor.Green; // (001 | 100) == 101, which is Red, Green
```

Comment: +1. It's worth pointing out that if explicit values aren't defined, it's sequential from 0. 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, etc. Secondly, that the `Flags` attribute does not affect how the values are created by default. It does affect the behavior of `ToString`, and also signals to IDEs whether or not the enum is intended to be used as flags.

Comment: I've tried this enum btiwise operation before and gave up. Now, I came back only to find out that I have to provide values for the enum. So, after 4, the next one is 8?

Comment: @Programmer Yep, then each subsequent one is twice the previous one.

Comment: Nice, it works now. Nearly went crazy for this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Even though Matthew's answer is correct and it's a very good answer (there's a "maxed out version" of the topic [here](http://www.alanzucconi.com/2015/07/26/enum-flags-and-bitwise-operators/)), I would keep it "generic" and a bit more simple and go another way: same behaviour used with Layer Masks. The limitation here, your enum can't have more than 32 items, though.

```
private void uncleFoo() {
    enum myNATO { Adam, Bravo, Charlie, Delta } //my enum with NATO codes
    int activeNATO = 0; //int to store selected NATO codes

    //some testing here
    activeNATO |= 1 << (int)myNATO.Adam;
    activeNATO |= 1 << (int)myNATO.Bravo;
    activeNATO |= 1 << (int)myNATO.Charlie;
    Debug.Log(activeNATO);
    Debug.Log("has  Adam? " + (activeNATO & 1 << (int)myNATO.Adam));
    Debug.Log("has Delta? " + (activeNATO & 1 << (int)myNATO.Delta));
}
```

Debug.Log will print "1" for Adam, and "0" for Delta, obviously.

Hope this helps ;)